# deleting a node from linked list, when we are already pointing to that node

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

1->2->3->4 list, we want to delete 3rd node.

```
List *temp = *list;
List *local = NULL;

if (temp->next != NULL) {
    while(temp->next->data != data)
        temp = temp->next;
    local = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp->next->next;

    delete local;
    local = NULL;
}
else
{
    delete (*list);
    *list = NULL;
}
```

here i was using local a node to store node address temporarily  , which i want to remove, is there any way to delete node without taking temporary variable ?

Comment: You need to save the old value of `temp->next->next` somehow, before `temp->next` is deleted. What's wrong which your current approach?

Comment: Offtopic, what will happen if you don't have in your list a node with value in data variable?

Comment: Current code is working, i just wanted to know if there is any way such that we can remove an extra local variable, if there is no such way then its fine, thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think there's another way. You have to store the **next** node and the **one you're deleting**.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to avoid this. If your concern here is about performance, you can probably count on your compiler to do the work of optimizing the code. If the concern is about clarity of code, I think that most C/C++ programmers would recognize what is going on here, and of course you could always add a comment if you feel the need.

Comment: Thanks KW, I had forgot that point, thanks for mentioning :)